# Faster way than Scanner or BufferedReader reading multiline data from STDIN?

Tags: java, performance, inputstream, textinput

Note: I am currently coding in java. I am looking to read input data into a string, one line at a time (or more), and I expect a lot of total lines.

Right now I have implemented

```
scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    separated = in.nextLine().split(" ");
    ...
}
```

because within the line my inputs are space delimited.

Unfortunately, with millions of lines this process is VERY slow and he scanner is taking up more time than my data processing, so I looked into the java.io libraries and found a bunch of possibilities and I'm not sure which one to use (`ByteArrayInputStream`, `FileInputStream`, `BufferedInputStream`, `PipedInputStream`). Which one should I use?

To specify, my data is being piped in from a text file, every line has either 4 or 6 words ended by a newline character, and I need to analyze one line at a time, setting the (4 or 6) words to an array which I can temporarily manage.
Data format:

```
392903840 a c b 293 32.90
382049804 a c 390
329084203 d e r 489 384.90
...
```

Is there a way where scanner can read 1000 or so lines at a time and become efficient or which of these datatypes should I use(to minimize speed)?

Sidenote: while experimenting I have tried:

```
java.io.BufferedReader stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(in.ready()){
    separated = in.readLine().split(" ");
    ...
}
```

Which worked well, just wondering which one works best, and if there's any way to, say, read 100 lines into data at once then process everything. Too many options looking for the optimal solution.

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap your `System.in` with a `BufferInputStream` like:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
Scanner in = new Scanner(bis);
```

because this minimises the amount of reads to System.in which raises efficiency (the BufferedInputStream).

Also, if you're only reading lines, you don't really need a Scanner, but a Reader (which has  `readLine()` and `ready()` methods to get a new line and see if there's any more data to be read).

You would use it as such (see example at [java6 : InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)):

(I added a cache size argument of 32MB to `BufferedReader`)

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 32*1024*1024);
while (br.ready()) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    // process line
}
```

From the InputStreamReader doc page:

> Without buffering, each invocation of
>   read() or readLine() could cause bytes
>   to be read from the file, converted
>   into characters, and then returned,
>   which can be very inefficient.

Comment: Hi Dan, this works really well. I'm using it without the scanner now, but still have a lot of time wasted because reading a line seems to take time. Is there a way that I can readLines(System.in, 1000) or something similar and just grab a bunch of lines since i expect (the majority of the time) if i have one line left i should have hundreds of thousands?

Comment: You can provide an additional argument to the `BufferedReader` constructor to provide the cache size. That way if you want to buffer a lot of data at a time, you could provide a really large buffer, like 32 MB.