# Fastest way for line-by-line reading STDIN?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, stdin

I'm looking for the most time-efficient way to read STDIN line-by-line.

The first line is the number of conditions to test.
All the following lines are conditions (strings) with a maximum of 100 000 characters.

I have already tried the following (plus result for 4 times 90 000 characters:

- Scanner with a while-loop (7255 ms)

  ```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
  long start = 0;
  int i = 1;
  while (i<=numberOfLines){
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      sc.nextLine();
      Debug.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms for scanner while");
      i++;
  }
  ```

  - Results :

    1. 3228ms for scanner while
    2. 2264ms for scanner while
    3. 1309ms for scanner while
    4. 454ms for scanner while
- Scanner with a for-loop (7078 ms)

  ```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
  long start = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i<= numberOfLines;i++){
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      sc.nextLine();
      Debug.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms for scanner for");
      //i++;     
  }
  ```

  - Results :

    1. 3168ms for scanner for
    2. 2207ms for scanner for
    3. 1236ms for scanner for
    4. 467ms for scanner for
- BufferedReader with a for-loop (7403 ms)

  ```
  try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  long start = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< numberOfLines;i++){
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      br.readLine();
      Debug.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms for bufferreader for");
      //i++;
  }
   } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
  ```

  }

  - Results :

    1. 3273ms for bufferreader for
    2. 2330ms for bufferreader for
    3. 1293ms for bufferreader for
    4. 507ms for bufferreader for
- BufferedReader with a while-loop (7461 ms)

  ```
  try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  int i=0;
  long start = 0;
  while(i< numberOfLines){
      start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      br.readLine();
      Debug.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms for bufferreader while");
      i++;
  }
   } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
  ```

  }

  - Results :

    1. 3296ms for bufferreader while
    2. 2358ms for bufferreader while
    3. 1307ms for bufferreader while
    4. 500ms for bufferreader while

While debugging the time taken, i noticed that the time-taken decreases after each read.
Is it possible to restrict the bytes that are initialized (f.e. : If you have a maximum of 100.000 chars, limit the scanner/bufferedreader to only initialize 100 000 chars. After a read it will need to refill itself with the next 100 000 chars)

Any ideas on this matter are more than welcome.

EDIT : Added the code for each scenario along with the time-taken per line read. Also changed 100.000 to 100 000 to read more easily.

Comment: Is `100.000` a hundred or a hundred thousand?

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your tests, possibly showing some code? Additionally, `i noticed that the time-taken decreases after each read` - do you mean the reads get faster?

Comment: a hundred thousand. Sorry, thought to make it clearer, but made it worse.

Comment: @Thomas : the test string is just a random generated string of 90 000 chars. I will edit my question with the code that I used and the results per line read

Comment: 1) while performance shouldn't differ from for performance - all cycle are essentially the same in Java. 2) As for decreasing time after each read that's just JIT warming up.

Comment: @Andrei LED : 1) Didn't know that. Saw on several threads to use while, because it could be faster then for. 2) Is there something I can do to decrease this time.

Comment: I myself would prefer BufferedReader since Scanner is more sophisticated and can do much more then just read next line. Have you tried your performance tests with more lines? Try, for example, 10 lines to see if the time can be decreased even more. Though I think 500 ms for 100 000 chars is good enough. And the last thing: set buffer size for BufferedReader to more than 100 000 (default buffer size is ~8Kb).

Comment: 500 ms would be perfect, but then I mean 500 ms as average for each line. When I try the same with 10 strings, I end up with the last string at 500 ms, but I try to keep the processing of 10 strings in total under 5 seconds. I've set the buffer size to 150 000, but there's no remarkable difference between the results.

Comment: There is a nice tool that could help you for such kind of micro-benchmarks: [Java Micro Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). [Real-life example](https://github.com/oblac/java-common-benchmarks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oblac/jcb/collection/ForLoopOverListBenchmark.java). Note that JMH documentation is basically embedded as comments in [JMH Samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/).

Comment: Which charset is your input encoded in? You can take a couple of shortcuts, if you know it's either just ASCII or just ISO_8859_1, because you can map bytes directly to chars.

Comment: Related (actually duplicated by): [Faster way than Scanner or BufferedReader reading multiline data from STDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172284/faster-way-than-scanner-or-bufferedreader-reading-multiline-data-from-stdin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looked inside `BufferedReader#readLine` source. There're several problems I see:

1. It uses StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder, which creates synchronization overhead.
2. Also there seems to be data copy overhead - not entirely sure, better check it out.
3. Dedicated monitor object in the BufferedReader and even more synchronization overhead.

You may take your chances with two things:

1. Writing your own buffering, which could save some time on double copying of the data.
2. Writing your own nextLine method that would use StringBuilder and go over source data with simple cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try these suggestions and see if it helps. Do you perhaps have any sample of these?

Comment: Have a look at source code of java.util.Properties.LineReader. The only it does is reading next line.

Comment: I copied the `BufferedReader` code, replaced `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder` and removed synchronization. Reading 3 million lines of a 200 MB file was insignificantly _slower_ (2050ms instead of 2000ms, down in the noise if you ask me) (averaged over 10 rounds, measured using bash's `time` command). Even [my own implementation](https://pastebin.com/3jiZeHUC) was 200ms slower than the `BufferedReader`.