# how the user would give the full path of a file using java

Tags: java, filepath

i have a problem and i think that someone maybe could help me because i am a little bit confused.
I had made a program where i am reading excel files and i am storing their data in a database.
In this database each excel file create a table. I have made the program and everything works fine up to here. Now, after the connection that i had done, i would like the user to be able to give the full path of the file that would read in the client and afterwards to continue the rest of the program, read the data and store them in a table. Could anyone help me how i would do this?  Below is the code for connection.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("get the connection");
        }
        catch( Exception e )
         {
         System.out.println( "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() );
         }

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kainourgia", "root", "root");
        DatabaseMetaData meta = (DatabaseMetaData) con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet res = meta.getCatalogs();
        System.out.println("List of the databases: ");
        while (res.next()){
            System.out.println (" " +res.getString(1));
        }
        //String filename = "C:\\Users\\myfiles\\Documents\\test5.xls";
        String fullPath = "C:\\Users\\myfiles\\Documents\\test5.xls";
        String Path = "C:\\Users\\myfiles\\Documents\\";
        String filename = "test5.xml";
        String[] parts = filename.split("\\.");
        String tablename = parts[0];
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Just use [Java Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read the input from the keyboard. A simple google search will give you the answer ;)

Comment: 1. use JFileChooser
2. create new dialog to choose files on your own
3. read path to file from command line params

Comment: Pass it in as command line argument

Comment: You can use the `Scanner` class for reading input from console or command window.

Comment: Another option, use command line arguments and find them in `args`.

Comment: ok i made it! Could anyone help me now how i continue in my program? What i have to do? I put the path in the console but the program didn't continue!Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Scanner class as follows:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String filename = scanner.nextLine();
```

The user can input the name of the File to the standard input. And in this case, the `nextLine()` method will read the line from the standard input of the system.

Answer (score 2):

You can either pass the file name as commandline argument to the java program like

**`java <classname> <filepath>`**

OR

You can read the filepath provided by user from stad input

Refer [Best way for line-by-line reading STDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008883/best-way-for-line-by-line-reading-stdin)