# Understanding the poor performance when reading lines from stdin via InputStreamReader into char[]

Tags: java, performance, optimization, profiling

In the course of competitive programming a log filter (in several programming languages / technologies) I found the performance of Java reading from `stdin` quite poor.

In the first place I reduced the problem down to the performance of reading lines from `stdin` (no text processing or regular expressions in place yet) compared to other technologies.

Inspired by the answer to *[Fastest way for line-by-line reading STDIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009887/1078886)* I wrote my own line reader, but it's up to 1.3x slower.

---

## Code under test implementation

### Code

**LineReader.java**

```
package org.acme.logfilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LineReader {

  private static final int DEFAULT_READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;
  private static final int INITIAL_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE = 128;

  private InputStreamReader isr;
  private int lineBufferSize;

  // To buffer the read from the input stream
  private char[] readBuffer;

  // The extracted line
  private char[] lineBuffer;

  // Bytes read from the input stream
  private int readBufferCapacity = 0;

  // Position in the read buffer
  private int readIdx = 0;

  // The line length remembered with the last readLine() 
  private int lineLength = 0;

  public LineReader(InputStreamReader isr) {
    this(isr, DEFAULT_READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }

  public LineReader(InputStreamReader isr, int readBufferSize) {
    this.isr = isr;
    this.lineBufferSize = INITIAL_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE;

    this.readBuffer = new char[readBufferSize];
    this.lineBuffer = new char[lineBufferSize];
  }

  public boolean readLine() throws IOException {
    // Copy reference & value for slightly improved performance
    char[] readBuffer = this.readBuffer;
    // A local reference improves performance slightly
    int readIdx = this.readIdx;
    // Index of the (target) line array (equals to the line length)
    int lineIdx = 0;

    while (true) {
      if (readIdx == readBufferCapacity) {
        // Read buffer not filled yet or exceeded
        // (The line buffer might not be complete yet)

        // Reset the read buffer index (it has exceeded)
        readIdx = 0;

        // (Re)fill the buffer ...
        readBufferCapacity = isr.read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.length);

        if (readBufferCapacity <= 0) {
          // Though the stream ended, we previously read a line 
          // without CR 
          return lineIdx > 0 ? true : false;
        }
      }

      if (lineIdx == lineBufferSize) {
        // Line buffer is full, create new buffer and "backup" line 

        // Remember current buffer before creating new one
        char[] oldLineBuffer = lineBuffer;
        // Extend by initial size
        lineBufferSize += INITIAL_LINE_BUFFER_SIZE;
        lineBuffer = new char[lineBufferSize];

        // Copy incomplete line to the bigger buffer ... 
        System.arraycopy(oldLineBuffer, 0, lineBuffer, 0, lineIdx);
      }

      char chr = readBuffer[readIdx];
      readIdx++;

      if (chr == '\n') {
        this.lineLength = lineIdx;
        // "Export" localized variables
        this.readIdx = readIdx;
        return true;
      }

      lineBuffer[lineIdx] = chr;
      lineIdx++;    
    }
  }

  public char[] getLine() {
    return lineBuffer;
  }

  public int getLineLength() {
    return lineLength;
  }
}
```

### Note on the code

At the moment it's acceptable that it won't handle CRLF newlines properly, that's not the matter (since it's performing worse with less features). To deal only with one `char[]` buffer was intentional. The idea was to spare any `StringBuffer` or repeated `char[]` allocation overhead and copying. Since the consuming program is intended to read only, not manipulate the strings I thought it would be a good idea to wrap the `char[]` as a `CharSequence` for char sequence input to other methods.

I'd never implement a log filter with such code if I can get only a tiny performance benefit. This is only for the course of improving the poor performance of `BufferedReader`.

## Test classes implementations

**FilterLogStdBufferedReader.java**

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, 32768 * 1024);

String line;
long lines = 0;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  lines++;
}
```

**FilterLogCustomLineparserExt.java**

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
LineReader reader = new LineReader(isr, 32768 * 1024);

long lines = 0;

while (reader.readLine()) {
  lines++;
}
```

## Profiling results

### `time()` results

```
$ time ( cat /ramdisk/1gb.txt | java -cp bin/ org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogStdBufferedReader )

real 8.10
user 6.08
 sys 3.73


$ time ( cat /ramdisk/1gb.txt | java -cp bin/ org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogCustomLineparserExt )

real 9.49
user 7.92
 sys 3.22
```

10 iterations have been averaged. The 1GB file with 79 chars per line was read from a ramdisk.

### -Xprof

`-Xprof` gives me an overview on how the JVM interprets and runs the code (how much time is spent interpreting code, or executing JIT compiled or native code).

#### Results

**FilterLogStdBufferedReader.java**

```
Flat profile of 9.80 secs (768 total ticks): main

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
  0.7%     5  +     0    org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogStdBufferedReader.main
  0.4%     0  +     3    java.io.FileInputStream.available
  0.4%     3  +     0    sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
  0.3%     2  +     0    java.io.BufferedReader.readLine
  ...
  2.2%    13  +     4    Total interpreted

     Compiled + native   Method                        
 45.3%   347  +     1    org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogStdBufferedReader.main
  0.8%     6  +     0    sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
  0.5%     0  +     4    java.io.BufferedReader.readLine
  0.4%     0  +     3    java.io.BufferedReader.readLine
  ...
 47.3%   354  +     9    Total compiled

         Stub + native   Method                        
 33.7%     0  +   259    java.io.FileInputStream.available
 16.7%     0  +   128    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.System.arraycopy
 50.5%     0  +   388    Total stub


Global summary of 9.80 seconds:
100.0%   777             Received ticks
  1.2%     9             Received GC ticks
  4.4%    34             Compilation
```

**FilterLogCustomLineparserExt.java**

```
Flat profile of 13.88 secs (1017 total ticks): main

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
  0.3%     3  +     0    org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogCustomLineparserExt.main
  0.2%     0  +     2    java.io.FileInputStream.available
  0.2%     2  +     0    org.acme.logfilter.LineReader.readLine
  0.2%     2  +     0    sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
  ...
  1.2%    10  +     2    Total interpreted

     Compiled + native   Method                        
 57.7%   587  +     0    org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogCustomLineparserExt.main
  1.7%    17  +     0    sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
  0.2%     1  +     1    org.acme.logfilter.LineReader.readLine
  ...
 59.8%   606  +     2    Total compiled

         Stub + native   Method                        
 24.0%     0  +   244    java.io.FileInputStream.available
 14.8%     0  +   151    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes
  0.2%     0  +     2    java.lang.System.arraycopy
 39.0%     0  +   397    Total stub


Global summary of 13.88 seconds:
100.0%  1018             Received ticks
  2.7%    27             Compilation
```

(For brevity I've removed blocks of lines with percentages <= 0.1% and replaced them with "...".)

#### Observation / conclusion

Observation:

- the JVM spends a bit more time compiling code for `FilterLogStdBufferedReader`,
- the JVM spends more time executing compiled code than it does executing native code in `FilterLogCustomLineparserExt`,
- `sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop` is called more often or is *found* longer active when called from `FilterLogCustomLineparserExt`,
- the time spend on interpreting code is negligible in both implementations,

Conclusion:

- `LineReader` cannot be optimized to make the JVM just-in-time compile more code (interpret less) and
- `LineReader` should be optimized to do "less unnecessary" stuff so that the (compiled) code does not "waste" so much time

### hprof=cpu=times results

`cpu=times` counts the calls to the methods and calculates how much the calls contribute to the CPU time.

#### Results

**BufferedReader**

```
$ cat /ramdisk/1gb.txt | java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=times,file=stdbufferedreader.hprof.txt -cp bin/ org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogStdBufferedReader

CPU TIME (ms) BEGIN (total = 321694) Sat Aug 26 09:42:52 2017
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1 28.49% 28.49% 13107201 301905 java.io.BufferedReader.readLine
   2 17.69% 46.17% 13107201 301906 java.io.BufferedReader.readLine
   3 17.59% 63.77% 13107154 301904 java.lang.String.<init>
   4 10.07% 73.84%       1 302038 org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogStdBufferedReader.main
   5  7.86% 81.70% 13107154 301903 java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange
   6  7.31% 89.01% 13107201 301826 java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen
   7  1.86% 90.87%  128061 301866 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
   8  1.00% 91.87%  128001 301894 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes
   9  0.97% 92.84%  128001 301880 java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.compact
  10  0.67% 93.51%      61 301898 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead
  11  0.66% 94.17%  128001 301888 java.io.FileInputStream.read
  12  0.48% 94.65%  128061 301849 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions
  13  0.41% 95.07%  128001 301889 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1
  ...
```

**LineReader (custom implementation)**

```
$ cat /ramdisk/1gb.txt | java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=times,file=custom.hprof.txt -cp bin/ org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogCustomLineparserExt

CPU TIME (ms) BEGIN (total = 103141) Sat Aug 26 09:39:02 2017
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1 34.11% 34.11% 13107201 301921 org.acme.logfilter.LineReader.readLine
   2 31.22% 65.32%       1 302011 org.acme.logfilter.FilterLogCustomLineparserExt.main
   3  5.75% 71.07%  128040 301886 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeArrayLoop
   4  3.10% 74.17%  128001 301914 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes
   5  3.01% 77.18%  128001 301900 java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.compact
   6  2.65% 79.83%  128001 301908 java.io.FileInputStream.read
   7  2.10% 81.93%      40 301918 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead
   8  1.46% 83.38%  128040 301869 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions
   9  1.24% 84.63%  128040 301890 java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode
  10  1.20% 85.83%  128001 301909 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1
  11  1.17% 86.99%  128040 301887 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeLoop
  12  0.91% 87.90%  127971 301916 java.io.BufferedInputStream.available
  13  0.85% 88.76%  128001 301910 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read
  14  0.61% 89.36%  127971 301917 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.inReady
  15  0.53% 89.90%  128040 301885 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.xflow
  16  0.52% 90.42%  128040 301870 sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.access$200
  17  0.48% 90.90%  256080 301867 java.nio.Buffer.position
  18  0.46% 91.36%  256080 301860 java.nio.ByteBuffer.arrayOffset
  19  0.44% 91.80%  256080 301861 java.nio.Buffer.position
  20  0.44% 92.24%  256002 301894 java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.ix
  21  0.43% 92.68%  256080 301862 java.nio.Buffer.limit
  22  0.43% 93.11%  256002 301895 java.nio.Buffer.remaining
  23  0.42% 93.53%  256080 301864 java.nio.CharBuffer.arrayOffset
  ...
```

#### Observation / conclusion

Observation:

- The custom implementation spends a bit more time in `readLine()`.
- The CPU time in the custom implementation is three times shorter (`total = 103141`).

Conclusion:

- The custom implementation does not call native code unexpectedly often.
- The CPU time values match the `user` time when *timing the profiled* executions. I assume this is due to the `BufferedReader` implementation running longer due to more code and thus more instrumentation. This is not contradictory to the reversed run time without profiling.

---

## Optimization attempts so far

- Making `lineIdx` and `readIdx` local helped a bit to improve the performance to the current (still poor) state
- Replacing multiple getters by a `CharSequence` directly returned by `readLine()` (it decreased the performance insignificantly)

## Question(s)

Is my interpretation of the profiler results correct?

What are the properties of the `LineReader` making it perform so bad compared to a `BufferedReader` which creates `StringBuffers` and `char[]` instances again and again and constantly copies data around?

How can the implementation be improved?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of problems with your `LineReader` implementation that make it suboptimal.

1. First of all, `readLine` is a large method with a complicated control flow that makes hard for JVM to apply optimizations.
2. `lineBuffer` is filled character by character, while it is faster to use bulk copy.
3. There is no obvious constraint on index variables when accessing `readBuffer` and `lineBuffer` arrays, so JVM will emit array bounds check on each array operation.

My suggestions are:

- Use a short separate loop to find the index of `\n` character. It will benefit from many JIT optimizations like loop unrolling, array bounds check elimination, better register allocation etc.
- Once you find `\n`, use `System.arraycopy` to fill `lineBuffer` at once.

Here is an example, not fully functional, but it may give you an idea of how this may look like.

```
public boolean readLine() throws IOException {
    do {
        int cr = findCR(readBuffer, readIdx, readBufferCapacity);
        if (cr >= 0) {
            lineLength = cr - readIdx - 1;
            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, readIdx, lineBuffer, 0, lineLength);
            readIdx = cr;
            return true;
        }
    } while (refill());
    return false;
}

private int findCR(char[] readBuffer, int pos, int limit) {
    // Ensuring that limit <= readBuffer.length helps JIT to eliminate array bounds check
    limit = Math.min(limit, readBuffer.length);
    while (pos < limit) {
        if (readBuffer[pos++] == '\n') {
            return pos;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Side notes**

- Your buffer size is too large, it has negative impact on CPU caches. Something between 32K and 256K should be better for performance.
- Do not use hprof, it modifies the code running and often gives distorted results. I believe [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) will be more precise; it also shows time spent in native and in kernel code.

Answer (score -1):

I use the below piece of code at competitive programming contests. This code piece was shared at codechef and around the web for a while now. Execution time will get reduced considerably :)

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    InputReader sc = new InputReader(System.in);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        //unimplemented.
    }
}

static class InputReader {
    private InputStream stream;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;
    private SpaceCharFilter filter;

    public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public int read() {
        if (numChars == -1)
            throw new InputMismatchException();

        if (curChar >= numChars) {
            curChar = 0;
            try {
                numChars = stream.read(buf);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }

            if (numChars <= 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return buf[curChar++];
    }

    public String nextLine() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = "";
        try {
            str = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        int c = read();

        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();

        int sgn = 1;

        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }

        int res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        }
        while (!isSpaceChar(c));

        return res * sgn;
    }

    public long nextLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;

        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        }
        while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public double nextDouble() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        double res = 0;
        while (!isSpaceChar(c) && c != '.') {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                return res * Math.pow(10, nextInt());
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        }
        if (c == '.') {
            c = read();
            double m = 1;
            while (!isSpaceChar(c)) {
                if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                    return res * Math.pow(10, nextInt());
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                m /= 10;
                res += (c - '0') * m;
                c = read();
            }
        }
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public String readString() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c))
            c = read();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        }
        while (!isSpaceChar(c));

        return res.toString();
    }

    public boolean isSpaceChar(int c) {
        if (filter != null)
            return filter.isSpaceChar(c);
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

    public String next() {
        return readString();
    }

    public interface SpaceCharFilter {
        public boolean isSpaceChar(int ch);
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Why is there a `Node` class? "Magically" is not a good explanation, please add a proper explanation.

Comment: @luk2302
Sorry about that, that was a typo while I pasted code from my IDE. 
I edited my response too, hoping that would avoid any misinterpretation. Thank you!